# How to get next 10 sundays by giving start date.?

Tags: php, codeigniter, date

How can i get next 10 Sundays by giving just current data,

Following is my code but it is between date ranges i just want to give start  date and get next 10 Sundays from start date(Without end date).

```
    $allweeks=array();
    $startDate = date('Y-m-d');
    $date = new DateTime($startDate);
    $interval = new DateInterval('P2M');
    $date->add($interval);
    $endDate=$date->format('Y-m-d');
    for ($i = strtotime($startDate); $i <= strtotime($endDate); $i = strtotime('+1 day', $i)) {

      if (date('N', $i) == 1)  
         $allweeks[]= date('n-j', $i);

    }
    foreach($allweeks as $wks)
    {
        $weeks=explode('-', $wks);
        echo '=Week of '.$weeks[0]."/".$weeks[1];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `DateTime` class or `strtotime` function for same:

Have a look on below code:

**Using `DateTime` Class**

```
$date = '2016-04-05';
$date = new DateTime($date);

// Modify the date it contains
for($i =0; $i < 10; $i++){
$date->modify('next sunday');

// Output
echo $date->format('l : Y-m-d');
echo '<br />';
}
```

**Using `strtotime` function**

```
$date = '2016-04-05';
// Modify the date it contains
for($i =0; $i < 10; $i++){
    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next sunday', strtotime($date)));

    echo date('l : Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
    echo '<br />';
}
```

**output**

```
Sunday : 2016-04-10
Sunday : 2016-04-17
Sunday : 2016-04-24
Sunday : 2016-05-01
Sunday : 2016-05-08
Sunday : 2016-05-15
Sunday : 2016-05-22
Sunday : 2016-05-29
Sunday : 2016-06-05
Sunday : 2016-06-12
```

Comment: Your output is not correct; the first Sunday after 2016-04-05 is 2016-04-10.

Comment: Yea, I know the code works properly ... you had just copied the wrong result.

Comment: But what if today is sunday and i want to include today in my 10 records(Today+next 9= total 10) for only next sundays excluding today above code is perfect .

Comment: @FahimAkhtar you can add some condition for today to check weather today is sunday or not. e.g. `$date->format('l') == 'Sunday'` then run loop 9 times

Comment: @FahimAkhtar so it can be consider as acceptable answer :)